# Spring cloud stream reactive kafka producer ack

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-function

Can someone point me to examples or documentation of Kafka producer written in Spring cloud stream reactive way to obtain an ack back when the publish to kafka broker is successful or when failed in a synchronous way?

Comment: With reactive the unit of work is the entire stream, not a single message like you would with imperative message handler. So, we have no control of individual messages. If you want that level of control, consider using imperative functions.

Comment: Just to add more for context. . . unlike the imperative function which gets invoked once per each message, reactive function gets invoke once (during initialization phase) for the life of the application. The framework simply connects the stream implemented by the user (via such function) to the message stream. After that s-c-stream has absolutely no control over message processing, error handling etc. That is the fundamental difference between reactive and imperative programming models - we handed control from us(s-c-stream) to them(reactive).

Comment: thank you yeah it makes sense, but I am on a reactive stack with webflux, cloud stream and functional programming. One requirement is I cannot afford to lose a message when I publish to kafka broker, I need to retry or fail that flow (stream) when the publishing failed. Is it recommend to use imperative style just for publishing when the whole stack is reactive ? trying to understand the best practices to meet the requirement.

Comment: Example :I am consuming event A from a topic using cloud stream with cloud  function , then store into some db and then transform the event to event B and publish to a different topic. If the publishing of event B fails due to broker connection or some errors I want to retry and not commit the offset of event A consumer, so that event A is not lost from the broker. If I cannot get an ack back from broker in reactive way, what would be the recommended /standard pattern to not lose that message ?

Comment: You can still interact with broker imperatively (e.g., in your flux.map(..) method using StreamBridge - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources